# Add events in the background with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html ul list of 10,000+ elements and want to add custom hover tooltip events and do some other processing to each one. To do this on document.ready takes 2-3 seconds and freezes the browser. How can I do this asynchronously so that the browser doesn't freeze?

I've been reading about setTimeout, jQuery queue and deferred, but maybe I'm too dense to understand it all. This guy had interesting stuff http://erickrdch.com/2012/05/asynchronous-loop-with-jquery-deferred.html

Here's my each() loop that adds the hover.

```
$('#biglist li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).hover(function(e){
        ...do stuff...
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why do you have it encased in a loop? try just applying hover to #biglist with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/), and then delegating to each li:

```
$('#biglist').on('hover','li', function(){
    // do crap
});
```

The .each() loop is likely wreaking havoc by doing processing on each item. As a side note, if you need to have different functions performed for mouseenter vs mouseleave, u need to use the XML format (using the .on() method is slightly different than the traditional .hover() method):

```
$('#biglist').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // do mouseenter crap
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        // do mouseleave crap
    }
},'li');
```

Either way this should greatly reduce CPU consumption from processing.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I didn't realize there was an alternative to each(). Thanks too, for giving the mouseenter/mouseleave bit because with your tip I added a mousemove too. It works a lot faster now.

Answer (score 3):

You should bind it to `#bigList` using [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), instead of on 10,000+ elements:

```
$('#bigList').on('hover', 'li', function(e) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: binding to the document isnt good news ... he has an ID, binding to the id, and specifying li is faster processing.

Answer (score 1):

Browser JavaScript does not support true concurrency (apart from cutting-edge HTML5 features, that is) so you can't have one process run in the background while the page continue to work normally.

The best you can do AFAIK is to cut your processing code into chunks as small as possible, then execute them with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, using a low value for delay (but preferably non-zero, so the rest of the page won't freeze).

Setting aside the fact that you don't need a different `hover` handler for each element, as others pointed out, if you need to do heavy processing of your received data (and such processing can't be done by the server) one way would be using a queue:

```
var queue = [];
setInterval(function() {
    var next = queue.shift();
    if ( next ) next();
},50);

...

$.each(lotsOfData, function(index, value) {
    queue.push(function() {
        // Code for processing the value
    });
});
```